# Sqlite Database not inserting

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sql-insert, android-cursor

I know it's a very basic question, but I can't seem to figure it out. My rows aren't being inserted in the database.

Anyone have a clue what is wrong?

```
 //this is the code where I try to insert the data

    dbAdapter.open();
    dbAdapter.EnterCreateHistory(DatabaseAdapter.WALKER_HISTORY_TABLE, "fdfsf", "fdfsf1", "fdfsf", "fdfsf", "fdfsf");
    dbAdapter.EnterCreateHistory(DatabaseAdapter.WALKER_HISTORY_TABLE, "fdfsf1", "fdfsf2", "fdfsf1", "fdfsf1", "fdfsf1");
    dbAdapter.EnterCreateHistory(DatabaseAdapter.WALKER_HISTORY_TABLE, "fdfsf1", "fdfsf3", "fdfsf1", "fdfsf1", "fdfsf1");
    dbAdapter.EnterCreateHistory(DatabaseAdapter.WALKER_HISTORY_TABLE, "fdfsf1", "fdfsf4", "fdfsf1", "fdfsf1", "fdfsf1");
    dbAdapter.EnterCreateHistory(DatabaseAdapter.WALKER_HISTORY_TABLE, "fdfsf1", "fdfsf5", "fdfsf1", "fdfsf1", "fdfsf1");

    Cursor walkerHistory = dbAdapter.getAllData(DatabaseAdapter.WALKER_HISTORY_TABLE);
 //here I check if the data is being inserted, 
//but the number of columns always comes back as 0
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Number of rows inserted:  "+walkerHistory.getCount(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Here is the OnCreate code inside the DatabaseAdapter:

```
   public void EnterCreateHistory(String tableName, String recommendationDate, String recommendation, String activityDate, String activity, String analyses){
    ContentValues values= new ContentValues();
    db = mdb.getWritableDatabase(); 

    values.put(RECOMMENDATION_DATE,recommendationDate);
    values.put(RECOMMENDATION,recommendation);
    values.put(ACTIVITY_DATE,activityDate);
    values.put(ACTIVITY, activity);
    values.put(MONITOR,analyses);

    long rowid=db.insert(tableName, null, values);
    rowid1=rowid;
    Log.d(TAG, "IDD"+rowid1);

}
```

Edit: I updated my code according to @MDMalik 's advice, but it's still not inserting.

Edit2: I am not sure if this is important or not, but I forgot to mention that the database used to work before. I had 4 entries with this same code, but it just stopped adding new ones.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
public void EnterCreateHistory(String tableName, String recommendationDate, String recommendation, String activityDate, String activity, String analyses){
ContentValues values= new ContentValues();

//    **//Add this line**
db = this.getWritableDatabase();       

values.put(RECOMMENDATION_DATE,recommendationDate);
values.put(RECOMMENDATION,recommendation);
values.put(ACTIVITY_DATE,activityDate);
values.put(ACTIVITY, activity);
values.put(MONITOR,analyses);

    long rowid=db.insert(tableName, null, values);
    rowid1=rowid;
    Log.d(TAG, "IDD"+rowid1);
}
```

Comment: I am sorry for the ignorance, but what would db be?
The way I implemented this, my db variable is SQLiteDatabase type, and it doesn't have that method.

Comment: Just saw your edit, I couldn't do that, so I did   

db = mdb.getWritableDatabase();

Where mdb is the DatabaseHelper.

Still didn't work though.

Comment: You need a ContentResolver and the URI to the Table:

//Instead of db = this.getWritableDatabase();       
ContentResolver contentResolver = mContext.getContentResolver();
and then 
long rowid=contentResolver.insert("URI",values);

Comment: @ChrisCarneiro what would the URI be exactly? I am sorry if this is a dumb question, but whenever I used the database on Android previously, I didn't need this. Thanks

Comment: Well if you read the doc of the ContentValues class you'll see this:
"This class is used to store a set of values that the ContentResolver can process."

So since you use ContentValues, I figured you were using a ContentProvider.

I suggest you read this tutorial:
http://www.grokkingandroid.com/android-tutorial-content-provider-basics/
And thent his one:
http://www.grokkingandroid.com/android-tutorial-using-content-providers/

Comment: I'll take a look at it. But it's odd because the way I used to do it didn't use ContentProvider or anything, so I never heard of it.